# Mean brightness and the standard deviation of columns in a gray scale image

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, map, code-review

I want to calculate the mean brightness and the standard deviation of columns in a gray scale image (8bit).

Can the following calculation code be made faster or/and shorter:

```
imageData = ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6qjE.png"], "Byte"];

dim = Dimensions@imageData;
list = Range@dim[[2]];

meanColumnBrightness = Mean@imageData[[All, #]] & /@ list;
stdDevColumnBrightness = StandardDeviation@imageData[[All, #]] & /@ list;
```

The result is:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

yWithErrors = 
 Transpose[{Transpose[{list, meanColumnBrightness}], 
   ErrorBar /@ stdDevColumnBrightness}]

Show[ErrorListPlot[yWithErrors], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Small], 
   Point[Transpose[{list, meanColumnBrightness}]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: why not Transpose？

Comment: Please post your solution?

Comment: actually, for mean part, simply do Mean will be okay

Comment: same image output~ great~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points to make here:

1. Always use `Listable` attributes of functions, that will speed things up.
2. When unnecessary, do not use symbolic processing, use numeric processing instead.

Thus, I'll first change the data to `N` form, then use `Listable` attributes of `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` to get the result in a shorter and faster code.

```
imgd = N@imageData;
Mean@imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
StandardDeviation@imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The `Mean` part accelerated for 10 times while the `StandardDeviation` part accelerated for 100 times.

Hope this can help you.

---

## Edit 1

When calculating in rows, try using "/@" instead of simple `Transpose` will be a good choice:

```
imgd = N@imageData;
a = Mean /@ imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
b = StandardDeviation /@ imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Actually I think this will be slower than Transpose at the first place, but as the result shows that this is a better solution, let's use this one.

I'm quite confused why this form is slower, I always consider using one function's `Listable` form will be better than `/@`. Intriguing......

So similarly, if you want to speed it up instead of making the code short, for your first problem, you can use this either......

```
imgd = N@Transpose@imageData;
a = Mean /@ imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
b = StandardDeviation /@ imgd; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: This is incredible ... wau ... how would you do it when you want to calculate the mean and standard deviation in rows instead of columns?

Comment: edited~ in edit 1you can find out how to calculate them in rows.

Comment: Great solution ...